# Updating a navigation property that is a relationship to the same type?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using code first and have several classes that have navigation properties between themselves.

Issue Class:

```
 public class Issue
{
    public Issue()
    {
        Complaints = new List<Complaint>();
        SubIssues = new List<Issue>();
    }
    [Key,ForeignKey("Complaints")]
    public int IssueID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual Issue ParentIssue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Issue> SubIssues { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Complaint> Complaints { get; set; }
}
```

The Complaint Class:

```
public class Complaint
{
    public Complaint()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public int ComplaintID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(2000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IssueID")]
    public virtual Issue Issue { get; set; }
    public int IssueID { get; set; }
}
```

The **Complaint** class is working fine. Where I am running into difficulties is with the **Issues** class which references the same table for **SubIssues** and **ParentIssue**. The idea is that each Issue record with IsSubCategory == false can have 0 to many related Issue records as a collection of SubIssues and each Issue record with IsSubCategory == true will have a 1 to 1 relationship with an Issue record as ParentIssue.

Because of some DBA standards I also need to specify the naming of the Foreign key fields, i.e. ParentIssueID rather than the Issue_ParentIssueID (or whatever it auto gens)

I would prefer to do this with data annotations but could use the OnModelCreating process if need be.

How would I go about fixing the issue class so that the proper tables are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IssueID` can't be both a primary and a foreign key to itself. You need a property (and field) `ParentIssueId`.

```
public int? ParentIssueID { get; set; }
```

The mapping, if using fluent mapping, should look like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>()
            .HasMany(i => i.SubIssues)
            .WithOptional(i => i.ParentIssue)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentIssueID);
```

`ParentIssueID` is `int?` because it's an optional relationship.